# llvm 8 install size

Tags: llvm

I recently compiled llvm from source since I wanted to look at 8. However, it is a whooping `56G` in size once installed. That seems excessive.

How can I reduce the size of the installation?

```
; du -h -d 1 -c .
41M     ./include
22G     ./lib
35G     ./bin
264K    ./share
28K     ./libexec
56G     .
56G     total
```

[image: size on disk]

Build using:

```
cmake3 -G Ninja  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/llvm -DLLVM_TEMPORARILY_ALLOW_OLD_TOOLCHAIN=1 -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="all" ../llvm
```

Comment: You never mention how you configured the project and how you built it. I'm assuming you built it with debugging symbols. My `clang-8` binary (on OpenBSD) is 36.8 MB.

Comment: @Kusalananda I build it following the [instructions on the web site](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html)

Comment: But you never read https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#frequently-used-cmake-variables and did not use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:Release`?

Comment: @Kusalananda I foolishly assumed that debug was not the default. /sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build LLVM in release mode by adding `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` to `cmake3` invocation.

The default is to build with debugging symbols, which will result in very large files.